# Parse command line parameters in assembly

Tags: assembly, command-line-arguments, dos, x86-16

Its a 16 Bit x86 Code. I have stored every command, for eg a "hi" command

```
cmd_hi db 'hi', 0
```

then i get the input string using

```
    mov di, sp        ; get input
    call get_string
    jcxz loop_start   ; blank line?
```

and compare it to the stored command

```
mov si, sp
mov di, cmd_hi    ; "hi" command
call strcmp
je .greetme
```

using a strcmp loop

```
strcmp:
.loop_start:
    mov al, [si]       ; grab a byte from SI
    cmp al, [di]       ; are SI and DI equal?
    jne .done          ; no, we're done.

    test al, al        ; zero?
    jz .done           ; yes, we're done.

    inc di             ; increment DI
    inc si             ; increment SI
    jmp .loop_start    ; loop!

.done:   
    ret
```

but now i want to add independent parameters to my function like 2 ints for eg

```
cmd> hi 1 2
```

What is the best way to parse the arguments in this way?

Comment: Your `are SI and DI equal?` comment is arguably wrong, and should be `are [SI] and [DI] equal?`

Comment: Look up how DOS passes the arg string to your program.  Unlike Unix/Linux, DOS doesn't word-split the string for you, you just get a flat string  (somewhere) and have to process quotes and spaces yourself.  And of course in any OS args like `1` will be the ASCII string `"1"`, not the integer `1`, so you'll need to do string->int yourself.

Comment: Somewhere = the [Program Segment Prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Segment_Prefix) (PSP)

Answer (score -1):

Normally, in case of .com file (I am not sure about .exe but as I remember it was the same) you have two copies of command line arguments in the memory segment to which the program is loaded. .com is loaded at 0x100h and the command line parameters should be found between 0 and 0x100h of the code segment.

Comment: Why minus? Please add comment why you not like the answer!